# Use np.fromfile to read data with specific behavior

Tags: python, numpy

For example, let's say I have a file with the following binary data:

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
```

I want to create a custom dtype `my_type` that will behave as following:

```
>> np.fromfile(..., dtype=my_type, count=2)
np.array([3, 7])
```

I.e. the custom dtype takes two bytes and sums their integer value.

The reason I want to do this is to prevent the need to post-process my data after using `fromfile` , is this possible?

If not, what's the most efficient way to achieve this with a large amount of data?

Comment: You can specify a compound `dtype`, or use a dtype that uses 2 bytes, 'uint16', but you can't define one that "performs" some sort of math on the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a new data type I would instead use `np.loadtxt` with a converter:

```
# Example input:
s = io.StringIO('0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04')
# Read the file
x = np.loadtxt(s,delimiter=' ',converters={0:lambda s: int(s,16)})
# Sum the result 2 by 2.
x = x[::2]+x[1::2]
```

And here I simply use a lambda function to convert each hexadecimal number into integer.

Comment: How can I read a binary file using `np.loadtxt`?